# It's that possible to detect a background beacon source generated by an iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon

I try to use an iOS device as a beacon(let's say my iPhone5), which should be detected by another iOS devices, let's say (my iPad).
**When both the devices are in foreground,** my iPad is able to detect the beacon signal generated by my iPhone correctly. From my `didRangeBeacons` delegate method, I did

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion) {
        if beacons.count > 0{
            print(beacons)
        }
 }
```

I logged the beacon info

```
[CLBeacon (uuid:<__NSConcreteUUID 0x124e483b0> AD065817-291B-4422-BD59-CBBFBDB81F17, major:9, minor:6, proximity:2 +/- 0.81m, rssi:-56)]
```

When my iPhone(the beacon) in a background mode(the screen is not active), I am not able to detect any beacon signal from my iPad, are there any solution for this scenario? I have done a lot of research online, but I couldn't find something that is illuminating.

Answer (score 2):

Monitoring for beacons works when an app is in the background because iOS is performing that service for the app. However ranging only works when the app is in the foreground. If short term background ranging is not enough then you need to enable the Background Modes option in the Capability tab of your project settings and use `UIBackgroundModes` set to `location` in your `Info.plist`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can range a beacon in the background. Normally iOS only allows you to do this for 10 seconds after you go to the background, however, you can use this code to extend your background awake time to up to 3 minutes:

```
func extendBackgroundRunningTime() {
    if backgroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid {
        // if we are in here, that means the background task is already running.
        // don't restart it.
        return
    }
    NSLog("Attempting to extend background running time")
    var self_terminate: Boolean = true
    self.backgroundTask = UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithName("DummyTask", expirationHandler: {() -> Void in
        NSLog("Background task expired by iOS")
        if self_terminate != nil {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(backgroundTask)
            self.backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
        }
    })
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {() -> Void in
        NSLog("Background task started")
        while true {
            NSLog("background time remaining: %8.2f", UIApplication.sharedApplication().backgroundTimeRemaining)
            NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(1)
        }
    })
}
```

You actually don't need background modes for this. You need to set NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in info.plist. Your phone will range any of the CLBeaconRegions you set it to look for. I like to use [this app](https://itunes.apple.com/sg/app/jetfuel-by-beaconsinspace/id1059513718?mt=8) to test with iBeacons because it provides simulation and detection, although there are many beacon simulator apps out there, or you can buy an actual ibeacon.

I would try to use ranging in the background as sparingly as possible, because this process can be battery intensive if done in excess. Try to use monitoring in situations where you don't need to know things like Proximity and RSSI that are provided through ranging in order to conserve battery life.

Answer (score 1):

Monitoring Beacons works well in foreground as well as in background.
Monitoring

Monitoring a region enables your app to know when a device enters or exits the range of beacons defined by the region. Imagine a museum with an audio guide application and beacons installed by the two entrances. The app is monitoring for a region encompassing both beacons (think: ‘all entrance beacons’ region) and is notified whenever the user enters the museum. Then it launches a notification, reminding users about the audio guide feature.

Ranging

While Monitoring enables you to detect movement in-and-out of range of the beacons, Ranging is more granular. It returns a list of beacons in range, together with an estimated proximity to each of them.Coming back to our museum example: imagine an "all beacons near the exhibits" region. The audio guide app can scan for all beacons in this region and then check which beacon is the closest. Since each beacon is associated with a particular exhibit, the app will play a description of an artwork relevant to the user’s context.

Ranging works only when the app is running, which most of the time means that the user is actively using the app. This also means that it only needs permission to "Access Your Location While You Use the App".

If you're sure you need persistent background ranging for beacons, you'll need to activate the Background Modes capability for your application—specifically, the Location Updates mode.

Note that for startRangingBeaconsInRegion to work in the background you'll also need to start Standard Location Updates via CLLocationManager's startUpdatingLocation (meaning you need both a CLLocationManager and an ESTBeaconManager in your app).

Note: In iOS 9, you also need to set the allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates property of your CLLocationManager to true.

(from community.estimote.com )
https://community.estimote.com/hc/en-us/articles/203914068-Is-it-possible-to-use-beacon-ranging-in-the-background-